# Kable highlighting the largest value in each row (R - Knitr)

Tags: r, dataframe, knitr, kable, kableextra

Let's use this dataframe:

```
x <- structure(list(`A. afarensis` = c(NaN, 41.624448481617, NaN, 
44.3444026007235, 45.637877314444), `A. africanus` = c(NaN, 40.8108406931158, 
NaN, 17.6702611050343, 28.8624817479424), `A. anamensis` = c(NaN, 
3.96543899879134, NaN, 13.4563973882188, 7.02306143133709), `Ar. ramidus` = c(NaN, 
3.31720723035651e-05, NaN, 0.00154294031842416, 7.49122553868537e-05
), Australopithecus = c(NaN, 6.97874566506872, NaN, 4.99347711237018, 
6.04930517572641), tooth = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to highlight in bold and with red background color the highest value per row, from the column `A. afarensis` to `Australopithecus`

I created this function:

```
fun_kable <- function(data){
  kable(data, digits = 2) %>%
    kable_classic(full_width = T, 
                  html_font = "Cambria", 
                  font_size = 10) %>%
    column_spec(ncol(data), bold = T, italic = T, color = "red")
}
```

When I run `fun_kable(x)` I would like to see also the highest value per row. How could I do this by using the previous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `cell_spec()`. Note that the rounding has to be done before hand, since using `cell_spec` transforms the variable to character. You can increase the number of digits, if the three 0's in column Ar.ramidus are problematic for you.

**Row Maximum**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

  max_values <- x |>
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2)) |>
  select(-tooth) |>
  purrr::pmap(pmax, na.rm = TRUE) |>
  as.numeric() |>
  na.omit()

x |>
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2)) |>
  mutate(across(-tooth, ~ if_else(row_number() %in% which(.x %in% max_values),
    cell_spec(.x,
      format = "html",
      color = "red", bold = TRUE
    ), as.character(.x)
  ))) |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(.x == "NaN", "", .))) |>
  kable(escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_classic(
    full_width = T,
    html_font = "Cambria",
    font_size = 10
  )
```

[image]

**Column Maximum:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
max_values <- x |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2)) |> 
  summarise(across(-tooth, max, na.rm = TRUE)) |> as.vector() |> unname()

x |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2)) |> 
  mutate(across(-tooth, ~if_else(row_number() %in% which(.x %in% max_values),
                               cell_spec(.x,format =  "html",
                                         color = "red", bold = TRUE), as.character(.x)))) |> 
  kable(escape = FALSE) |> 
  kable_classic(full_width = T, 
                html_font = "Cambria", 
                font_size = 10)
```

[image]

**test.qmd**

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
...
````

Comment: Hi @Julian, thanks, but in your example, you are retrieving the highest value in each column, rather than the highest value in each row. How could you adapt the code to use rows rather than columns?

Comment: My bad, I make an edit

Comment: Thanks, minor note. How can we get rid of the NaN values?

Comment: Would like the entries to be blank? Or filled with "-"?

Comment: Blank is my preference

Comment: I edited the line  `mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(.x == "NaN", "", .)))`

Comment: Thanks. It is curious because when I run this in RStudio I can see the highlighted values. However, when I knit in HTML, the highlighted values are not colorized, any idea @Julian?

Comment: For me it works fine, I add a yaml for a .qmd so you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment to Julian's answer. So I have to post as a new answer here.

If there are multiple values in same row accidently match with max_values in other rows, those values would also be highlighted.

row_number() %in% which(.x %in% max_values)

should be change to

.x == max_values[row_number()]